# Scope on each last elements of a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, has-many

Let's say I have a has_many relation between User and Messages.

I'd like to set a scope to be able to filter users by the ones who have something in the **last** message they posted. So searching only among each user's last message.

Below I got the results among all messages...

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages

    scope :filter_by_last_messages, lambda { |value|
        joins(:messages).where("messages.content = ?", value)
    }
end
```

Comment: i don't think that you can do this without subqueries in sql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by creating a belongs_to relation with the last message, in my User class.

```
belongs_to :last_message, :class_name => 'Message'
```

I set my last message in an after_create in Message class.
Then my scope is simply as follow:

```
scope :filter_by_last_messages, lambda { |value|
    joins(:last_message).where("content = ?", value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in one shot in a scope is not possible but you could do this:

```
scope :last_message, joins(:messages)
         .select("contacts.*, messages.content")
         .order("messages.created_at")
```

In your controller:

```
if @contact.last_message.content == value
  do_something
end
```

So a little bit can be scoped.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.